# How To Hash Social Security Numbers When Used As Identifiers

Tags: encryption, hash, sha256, sha

I have a service that let's users store information (such as messages, videos', etc.) for their extended family online to be shared when they pass away. Ex - Send this video to my nephew when I pass way telling him I love him.

I have a JSON structured database that stores a users social security number as an identifier to their profile.

```
 $salted_hashed_ssn: {
    //important information for extended family such as vidoes and email addresses
   }
```

When a user dies, their closest family members go to my site and input the deceased person's social security number. I then hash those and see if a match is made in my database. If a match is made, we then run functions to share the important information for the extended family.

Preparing for the worst, I want to store the social security numbers as securely as possible. Because I only need to use the social security numbers as a identifier, I don't have to store the raw/plain text ssn values. Therefore, I can hash the ssns but I need to salt them to protect against lookup tables. My issue is that when the users input the deceased user's social security number I don't have a way to see which salt key was used.

To make it random and prevent against lookup tables, how would you recommend I salt my social security numbers? Should I just take x number of characters each time? Ie - always grab the first 4 characters of the social security number, hash those, and them to the full SSN and then rehash?

let salted_hashed_ssn = SHA256(First 4 characters of SSN) + SHA256(SSN) ?

How would you recommend setting up the salt and hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat your SSN in the same way you would treat a password.  Remember, a salt doesn't have to be secret, it just has to be **different** for each entry.  So simply store your salt alongside your hash, this is perfectly safe.

I wouldn't recommend using SHA256 here, however.  Use `bcrypt` instead.  It handles the salt for you, which means you don't need to worry about the advice above anyway.  It's also far more resistant to brute forcing.  The SHA family was not designed for hashing in the way you are using it.

Comment: In this case I don't think a salt buys you anything. An iteration count helps though.

Comment: Thanks Luke. The problem I have is I can't store the salt under the user because after the person dies and his family member uses my site to add the SSN I don't know which user the inputted SSN applies to. The only value I have is the SSN, and a list of salted_hashed SSNs, I can't see which salt was used for the current SSN. However, thanks for sharing bcrypt. Would I have to store and re-use the same salt when I "decrypted" ? Or does bcrypt automatically apply and use a salt?

Comment: Ahhh, I misunderstood part of your original question.  You'll be better off using SHA256 with an iteration count like James suggested.  Have a look at PBKDF2.  Have a high enough iteration count that it takes about ~100-200ms to compute to avoid someone brute forcing your database, should it leak.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I really appreciate the help. Do I still need a salt with PBKDF2? Wouldn't I need to use the same salt on both ssns to get the same end result?

Comment: Yeah, having a static salt for PBKDF2 will be necessary for this to work.

Comment: And even though it's static, because of the iterator it would take too long to brute force. I plan to use this library: https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/ ... For PBKDF2, would you recommend a 128, 256, or 512 bit key? And what would you recommend for the iteration count?   ..... var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8); var key512Bits1000Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000 }); ?

Comment: You aren't hashing on the client side right?  Don't do that.  And don't use CryptoJS...  What is your server side language?

Comment: I planned to SHA256 the ssn on the client, then send that to my node server. Use the SHA256 ssn as the "Secret Passphrase" . How does that sound and what library should I use for Node?

Comment: Technically you could hash client side, but browser crypto is still a bit of a liability IMO.  I'd send the SSN to your server (over HTTPS, obviously) and then hash there.  Node has SHA256 built in.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Didn't realize it was built in. How about this: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback ... Should I use sha512 or sha256 ?

Comment: Yep, use that.  And it doesn't really matter.  Probably SHA256, less storage space in the database.

Comment: Great. Last question, how many iterations would you recommend? The most amount of time I will ever have to run this hash on my server in one day is ~7000 (amount of people that die everyday).

Comment: I'd aim for ~200ms of computation time, so benchmark it and see.  Will probably be around ~40000 ish but hard to know.

Comment: Makes sense. Ok one more question, last one:) What does keylen mean in "crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, callback)" ... is that length of final key/hash? With SHA256, ok if I make keylen 256?

Comment: Yeah your key length should be the output size of the hash you're using.  So yeah, 256 bits.

Comment: thank you! Will upvote you once I can (I'm at 14 points now). Really appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171122/discussion-between-will-and-luke-joshua-park).